# AWS Lambda Function not converting files with .DLL reference

Tags: python, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dll

I have been trying to convert newly uploaded files to a different format using a .DLL reference on my python code. The packages im using are `pythonnet` which allows me to use `clr` for referring to my .DLL file (The .DLL file helps for the conversion).

**My Lambda Function goes like --**

```
import boto3
import clr
import os
import tempfile

# Load the external .dll file
clr.AddReference("/RxLibrary.dll")
import RxLibrary

# Initialize S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get bucket and object key from the event
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    # Define the destination bucket
    destination_bucket = 'destination-bucket-name'

    # Download the source file to a temporary directory
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        input_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'input.rxd')
        output_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'output.mf4')

        s3.download_file(source_bucket, object_key, input_file_path)

        # Convert the input file using the provided code
        RxLibrary.RxLib.ConvertData(input_file_path, output_file_path)

        # Upload the converted file to the destination bucket
        s3.upload_file(output_file_path, destination_bucket, os.path.basename(output_file_path))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': f'Converted file {object_key} and uploaded to {destination_bucket}'
    }
```

**The Error message on AWS --**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Failed to create a default .NET runtime, which would\n                    have been \"mono\" on this system. Either install a\n                    compatible runtime or configure it explicitly via\n                    `set_runtime` or the `PYTHONNET_*` environment variables\n                    (see set_runtime_from_env).",
  "errorType": "RuntimeError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    import clr\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/clr.py\", line 6, in <module>\n    load()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pythonnet/__init__.py\", line 131, in load\n    set_runtime_from_env()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pythonnet/__init__.py\", line 114, in set_runtime_from_env\n    runtime = _create_runtime_from_spec(spec)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/pythonnet/__init__.py\", line 82, in _create_runtime_from_spec\n    raise RuntimeError(\n"
  ]
}
```

**It is clearly seen that AWS is unable to use .DLL for the conversion**. Can anyone help me out please?
I Tried various methods online to rectify this problem, but was unable to do so..

Answer (score 0):

This line: `"  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    import clr\n",` indicates that you aren't even getting to the import of your DLL, you can't even import the `clr` module.

Make sure that your Lambda is running in a compatible .NET environment, and first just get the basic `import clr` statement working and nothing else. (You may have to consult the setup instructions for creating a Lambda in C#, in order to get the .NET stuff configured.) Then you can start trying to load your DLL.

You will probably also have to work out the details of building your Lambda using a layer that contains both your .py script and the DLL.

(And probably don't use a path that is rooted at '/' to the DLL in your call to `addReference`.)

EDIT:

Additional research by @roganjosh points to [these docs](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet#net-core) on the `clr` module. Note that it indicates that Mono will be used in Linux or MacOS environments, .NET in Windows environments. So if you are deploying on a non-Windows environment, be sure that Mono is available.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dumb here but it strikes me that the OP doesn't load env vars. Might it just be a case of a missing `python-dotenv`?

Comment: Very possibly, only the OP knows for sure.